# Regex: How to change/replace lowercase and uppercase letters of the html TAG content:

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I want to change/replace lowercase and uppercase letters into a html TAG

`<meta name="keywords" content="Mother's, Sacrifice"/>`

Answer (score 0):

SEARCH: `(?:\G(?!^)|<meta name="keywords" content=)\s*\K([^<\s])([^<\s]*)`

REPLACE BY:  `\L$1$2`  or  `\L$1\L$2`

should become

```
<meta name="keywords" content="mothers's, sacrifice"/>
```

SEARCH: `(?:\G(?!^)|<meta name="keywords" content=)\s*\K([^<\s])([^<\s]*)`

REPLACE BY:  `\U$1\U$2`  or  `\U$1$2`

should become

```
  `<meta name="keywords" content="MOTHER'S, SACRIFICE"/>`
```